# Auto-generate dropdown lists (data validation)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Excel sheet which calculates the project cost, with the cost split u into 9 main groups (of which each into 9 groups and those again into 9 subgroups).

When a subgroup (like SUBGROUP 002) item consist of multiple parts (e.g. a door consists of wood, a door knob, nails, etc.), I get a few quotations from suppliers and insert those below the subgroup item.

I was wondering, since this is a 3000+ row sheet, if it was possible as soon as a quotation is added below a subgroup item to automatically generate a dropdown list in the subgroup item cost cell?

preferably with the list auto-updating if an additional quotation is subsequently added.

I have tried adding a macro that generates a new row and a dropdown list within it but I don't know how to do this independent of the cell where it gets generated:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A6").Select
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown

Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D5").Select
With Selection.Validation
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, _
Formula1:="=Sheet2!$D$6:$D$9"
.IgnoreBlank = True
.InCellDropdown = True
End With

End Sub
```

[image: example]

Comment: `generate a dropdown list in the subgroup item cost cell` Where is item cost cell? What's on dropdown list?

Comment: Sorry. Updated the photo It got cut off.

Comment: What's the logic of `generates a new row`?

Comment: Seemed like a convenient way to make the person working on the sheet aware of the macro. SOURCE: Twopersent YT  video https://youtu.be/iysXiWbut14?si=oeSGNp17BKbZfORe

Comment: Please post your code in OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The code dynamically update data validation.
- Please share more detail if provided code does not meet your needs.

```vb
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If Selection.CountLarge > 1 Then
        ' Multi-cells selection
        MsgBox "Please select a single cell."
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Dim iRow As Long
        ' Inert row
        Selection.EntireRow.Insert
        iRow = Selection.Row
        Cells(iRow, "D").Validation.Delete
        Dim sTxt As String
        Const MGRP = "MAIN GROUP"
        Const SGRP = "SUBGROUP"
        Dim arrData, i As Long, iStart As Long, iEnd As Long, lastRow As Long
        lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        ' Load data from column B
        arrData = Range("B1:B" & lastRow).Value
        ' Locate previous SUBGROUP
        For i = iRow - 1 To 2 Step -1
            sTxt = UCase(Trim(arrData(i, 1)))
            If Len(sTxt) > 7 Then
                If Left(sTxt, Len(SGRP)) = SGRP Then
                    iStart = i
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next
        If iStart = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Can't locate the SUBGROUP before row " & iRow
            Exit Sub
        End If
        ' Locate next SUBGROUP / MAIN GROUP
        For i = iRow + 1 To lastRow
            sTxt = UCase(Trim(arrData(i, 1)))
            If Len(sTxt) > 7 Then
                If Left(sTxt, Len(MGRP)) = MGRP Or Left(sTxt, Len(SGRP)) = SGRP Then
                    iEnd = i
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next
        If iEnd = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Can't locate the SUBGROUP/MAINGROUP after row " & iRow
            Exit Sub
        End If
        ' Update data validataion
        Dim sFormula As String
        sFormula = "=" & Cells(iStart + 1, "D").Resize(iEnd - iStart - 1).Address
        With Cells(iStart, "D").Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=sFormula
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: This is just what I needed. I will try to apply in your code now when MGs, Gs & SGs have each a specific name and post it here once finished. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Good to know, you may need to modify some code lines about how to located the previous/next subgroup.